# Need help figuring out infinite loop

Tags: c, while-loop, infinite-loop

This is a simplified version of my code:

```
void calc(char *s)
{
    int t = 0;
    while (*s)
    {
        if (isdigit(*s))
            t += *s - '0';
        else
            ++s;
    }
    printf("t = %d\n", t);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    calc("8+9-10+11");
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is with the while loop running forever, though I'm expecting it to stop after the final digit `1`. And my expected output is `t = 20`.

Comment: Your output will be "t = 8". Your code processes strings by adding all the digits together, with no regard for the operators. Also, you should consider using `strtol()` to process the numbers. `int t = 0; while(*s) { if(isdigit(*s)) t += strtol(s, &s, 10); }` would actually do the trick I believe, at least until you want to add multiplication and division. Even then you should still stick with `strtol()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`s` is not incremented if `*s` is a digit, consider removing the else clause, making the code into this:

```
while (*s)
{
    if (isdigit(*s))
        t += *s - '0';

    ++s;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

@Hasturkun has given you the right answer, but this is the kind of a thing a debugger could help you with, if you have one available. Step through the code and you'd quickly see it's not executing the `++s;` line.

Answer (score 0):

your else condition is not fulfilled

try this

if (isdigit(*s))

t += *s - '0';

```
 s++;
```